# Any virtualisation software that works with... gasp... Windows 95 as the *host* O/S?

Tags: windows, virtualization, symbian

I know this sounds crazy, but is there any VMWARE/Virtualbox type software that was around back in the days of Windows 95?
Reason I ask is that I just got a Nokia E71 (hooray) and have successfully run Windows 3.1 on it though DOSBOX. I'm told Win95 is also possible. I've got a bit of a thing about putting O/Ss places they shouldn't go - I'd really love to virtualise Damn Small Linux within Windows 95 if at all possible.
And yes, I know this will be pointless and unusably slow...
Many thanks

Comment: I'll buy the theory that you've got a really *strange* idea of fun, but if you have some secret project in mind for this, inquiring minds want to know!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can find an older version of Virtual PC for windows you might be able to get it running. A quick google search showed VPC for Win v5 supported 98SE so v 4 or 3 if you can find them might work (although i *think* Connectix only released mac versions back then). Also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Virtual_PC#Table_of_supported_operating_systems) seems to think you can get partial functionality as a host with VirtualPC 2004 and 2007!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) maybe?

If you can find something for Win98 you could install IE4+Shell Update on Win95 and it might just work.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I thought I was doing it, it turns out that VMWare Workstation 1.0 was an NT/W2K only release. Bad memory (on me) I guess.

Doing VM on 95/98/ME would be really challenging (above and beyond the mere processor problems) compared to the NT/2K environments, due to how the operating systems handled memory.

Answer (score -1):

I am 99% sure that there is none.

Comment: Thank you - I had a suspicion that may well be the case.

First time using S/O today - I'm so impressed...